# Hadoop MapReduce - single reducer is loaded heavily

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I am running a pig script which looks like

```
<something>
<something>
B = GROUP A by bucketid PARALLEL 200;
C = FOREACH B {
      sorted = SORT A by field1, field2 ...;
      GENERATE FLATTEN(sorted);
    }
STORE C INTO 'output' USING MultiStorage(output, '8', 'gz');
```

The field `bucketid` takes 200 different values and hence I am setting PARALLEL to 200 with the expectation that each reducer will take care of one group. However, some reducers do nothing while other reducers take care of more than one group. What is the idea behind this?

The real issue I am facing is, one reducer `R` lags behind other reducers and the task log says `merging 13GB of data` (and the reducer is in reduce phase). However, based on my input data, I do not expect `R` to be processing that big amount of data. Once `R` finishes, the output part files generated by it is only `350 MB` (of gzip format) and if I decompress, it comes to only `6 GB`. So I am wondering, why the log says `merging 13 GB of data` when the reducer is running. Any reasoning behind this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have any tests that detail the distribution of bucketid values? (you could run another foreach over B to get the COUNT of A). Also what is field '8' in your schema - is your 350MB/6GB output file just for one key?

Comment: I have data for each day and based on the runs from other successful days, each bucket size varies from 1MB to maximum of 290MB. while one reducer is stuck, I can see the output generated by other reducers and infer which buckids this reducer (the last one currently stuck) is supposed to be processing. The 350MB/6GB is for a combination of 4 bucketids with one of the bucket being 290MB and others are small. As I said, after it completes (taking a long time), the output produced by it is 350MB only (the delta between the final output size and the output size when the reducer was running).

Comment: @ChrisWhite Field 8 is the bucketid (I want to store the records based on the bucket id).